Discord-Reddit integration or RSS Feeds of content with flairs in subreddits
Is there a way to get a feed of all posts with a certain flair in a subreddit into Discord? I think there is a RSS bot so RSS is also another way to do so if Reddit supports it?
I've asked in Discord-Reddit integration or RSS Feeds for searching for flairs in subreddits : r/help
